# Firebase crash error: symbolFileMappings:upsert: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, firebase-crash-reporting

I have done all the required steps in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios to setup firebase crash reporting for my project. Then I set the run script as follow:

```
#Replaced GOOGLE_APP_ID 
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:app:Id 
#Replaced the Path to serviceAccount.json
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload sym"${SRCROOT}/myProjectFolder/ServiceAccount.json"
```

I have read all the available links about firebase crash installing some said to check the "Run script only when installing", this will remove the error but will not send the crash to firebase console. On the other hand when I check "Show environment variables in build log" only I get the following error:

> /Users/test/Documents/Projects/myproject/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:377: error: symbolFileMappings:upsert: Request contains an invalid argument.

Xcode 8.2.1

- Actually I have done all these steps in another project and it works fine but I have problem in this project. Is there any reason for this error?

Comment: Is that literally what your script looks like?

Comment: What's your GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman No I replaced my googleService-Info.plist to it

Comment: @Jay Yes, I copied the Apple ID from my google plist

Comment: Most often, when you get a Crash reporting error at compile time, it's because it's having trouble finding the Service Account json file. Can you double-check that it's correct? Maybe try putting in an absolute path and see if that helps at all.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I changes it's path and copied the file so many places to check if there is a problem with the path but I'm sure it's all correct

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but if you try then your problem may be solved.

1. accept ToS at https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Give "Editor" role to your Service Account created for uploading symbols as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#set_up_crash_reporting